# GitLab Pages CI hugo with asciidoctor (low maintenance)

Tags: gitlab-ci, hugo, asciidoctor

What is the best low maintenance / future proof way to use GitLab Pages to build a hugo site with asciidoc pages (using asciidoctor).

There are some images on DockerHub, but they don't have reliable maintenance.

Ideally, I think it would be best to use the GitLab Pages image for hugo (extended) and install the asciidoctor gem.

Comment: Maybe this example could help: https://gitlab.com/ca_water_data/ca_water_data_blog, [mentioned here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/help-getting-hugo-blog-to-display-posts-on-gitlab-pages/27980). Its [`gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/ca_water_data/ca_water_data_blog/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) does install asciidoctor.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't use a hugo image. I think it would be easiest to us the hugo image

Comment: OK. Images like [rraghur/docker-hugo-asciidoctor](https://gitlab.com/rraghur/docker-hugo-asciidoctor) seem old indeed.

Comment: yes, indeed I was looking at that one and some others (Brain Klein, another one).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the steps are:

1. install ruby
2. gem install asciidoctor
3. whitelist asciidoctor

The first two are performed in gitlab-ci.yml and the final step in config.toml.

Demo: https://gitlab.com/bquast1/bquast1.gitlab.io

The security policy change to whitelist asciidoctor is at the end of the config.toml file.